# fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I got this problem when I tried to run a simple cpp programme with vs code.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int a,b;
int main()
{
    int c;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    c = a + b;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

problem:

```
In file included from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
         from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6361,
         from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/string:52,
         from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
         from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
         from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
         from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
         from E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
         from c:\Users\Wolfram\Desktop\ss\project\a+b.cpp:1:
E:/software/wingw64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include_next <stdlib.h>
       ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

It confused me a lot. There wasn't this problem just a week ago. What should I do next?

Comment: What have you changed on your computer since a week ago?

Answer (score 0):

try to install libc6-dev, it will fix the problem